# JasperPrintManager.printReport(jasperPrint,true)

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a print button in jsp page that prints a report created in jasper.
What does calling JasperPrintManager.printReport(jasperPrint,true) in a jsp page actually do?
I imagine it has to invoke a javascript command to bring up the print dialog and sends the data to it.  It is not working for me. any idea?

Answer (score 2):

No javascript whatsoever. JSP pages are compiled to regular `HttpServlet`s, so perhaps it is executed on `doGet(..)` i.e. on loading of the page. This however prints the document **on the server**.
If you want to print on the client, then you will need an Applet. Or, better, export in PDF and send the PDF to the user for printing.

Comment: I think that is incorrect, calling in jsp JasperPRintManager.printReport does bring up the print dialog, so some javascript has to be involved.

Comment: No. The print dialog is shown because you test on localhost, and in fact this is the dialog opened on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Export your JasperPrint file to a PDF file. Set the content type on the response to "application/pdf".
Finally redirect the response with the streamed PDF.

You can do it in one JSP, but thats not the best solution, better to create your own ReportServlet